# Get a list View GUID by View name using JSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I have the following code in which i trying to get both the list GUID (working) and the list View GUID by the name of the view, which is not working.

```
function getLists() {


lists = web.get_lists();
context.load(lists, "Include(Id, Title, Hidden, ItemCount, Views)");
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

}

function onSuccess() {
var ul = $("#listsList");
var listsEnum = lists.getEnumerator();
while (listsEnum.moveNext()) {
    var list = listsEnum.get_current();
    if (list.get_title() == "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX") {
        var title = list.get_title();
        var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("Excel Export");
        var elem = $("<li>" + title + " with GUID " + list.get_id().toString() + " view GUID:" + viewID + "</li>");
        ul.append(elem); // append the details to a list
    }
}


}

function onFail(sender, args) {
alert("Request failed: " + args.get_message());
}
```

I'm getting the following error in JS

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get_view'

Appreciate any feedback.

**I'm now using  var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("Excel Export"); but this is bringing  back [object Object].
Do i need to parse the object??**

***I have marked tyshock's response as the answer as it was his comment on enumerating through the list views that gave me my final solution.I also found the following code very useful in arriving at my working code - found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409050%28v=office.14%29.aspx).***

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script type="text/ecmascript" language="ecmascript">

var viewCollection = null;
function runCode() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var listCollection = web.get_lists();
        var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Tasks");
        this.viewCollection = list.get_views();

        var viewInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
        viewInfo.set_title('MyView');
        this.viewCollection.add(viewInfo);

        clientContext.load(this.viewCollection);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var viewInfo = 'Tasks list current views: \n\n';
    var viewEnumerator = this.viewCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var view = viewEnumerator.get_current();
        viewInfo += view.get_title() + '\n';
    }
    alert(viewInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>

 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Run Code" onclick="runCode()" />

 </asp:Content>
```

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To fetch the collection of views, you need to use:

```
var views = list.get_views();
```

[get_views()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245667.aspx)

If you have a reference to the list, you can get the specific view by name using:

```
list.get_views().getByTitle("YOUR VIEW TITLE");
```

There is a getView(GUID) method on the List object, and it requires a GUID as its parameter, not the list name.

Comment: Thanks but i only know the View name and not the GUID

Comment: You can use the enumerator to loop through the views and identify the one with the matching name.  At that point, you can reference its GUID.  You can also call 'getByTitle()' from the view collection to get the named view.  I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks tyshock...i will give that a try...a little  unsure how to enumerate through the views...

Comment: Updated my question...trying to use list.get_views().getByTitle("YOUR VIEW TITLE"); but get an [object Object]?

Comment: It sounds like that object is indeed the view.  Try to access view.get_title () and it should be your view name.  See the following page for the object properties:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245986.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tyshock..looking at that link the View has not method get_id.  I can see the id is there in the JSON header info...driving me nuts!

Comment: It has get_id().  Click 'Properties' under 'Members' from that link and you'll see that the API actually calls 'getter methods' to access each property.  More info here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245968.aspx

Answer (score 4):

In your example there is an error on line (as the message says):

```
var viewID = list.get_view("Excel Export");
```

There is no method named `get_view()`, but [SP.List.getView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246007.aspx) and it returns `SP.View` and accepts view identifier (`SP.Guid`) as an argument

If you would like to get view by title, the best candidate, would be, probably:

```
var view = SP.List.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
```

### How to get View via CSOM

[SP.List.getView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246007.aspx):

```
var view = SP.List.getView(viewId)
```

[SP.List.defaultView property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850934.aspx):

```
var view = SP.List.get_defaultView()
```

[SP.ViewCollection.getById Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246456.aspx):

```
var view = SP.List.get_views().getById(viewId);
```

[SP.ViewCollection.getByTitle Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247117.aspx):

```
var view = SP.List.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
```

### Example

```
function getListView(url,listTitle,viewTitle,OnSuccess,OnError) {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext(url);
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
    context.load(view);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       OnSuccess(view);
    },OnError);        
}

getListView('https://conntoso.sharepoint.com/',
'Phones',
'Manufacturer',
function(view){
    console.log(view.get_id().toString());
},
function(sender,args){
    console.log('Error occured:' + args.get_message());
}
);
```

Comment: Thanks but I doing all this in JSOM and can use the SP.List

Comment: SP.List  is just the class name of List client object in JSOM, in your case it is: var list = ...

Comment: Thanks for the input i tried a few things out but ended up with a [object] [object] output thin i will need to try the enumerate method tyshock mentions.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this solution:

```
function ResolveListGuidFromName(webUrl, listName, viewName){
var guid;
var filter = "View[DisplayName='"+ viewName +"']";
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetViewCollection",
    async: false,
    webURL: webUrl,
    listName: listName,
    completefunc:function (xData, Status) {
        guid = $(xData.responseXML).find(filter).attr("Name");
    }
});
return guid;
}
```

It requires the use of [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

Original code had been posted here: [LINK](http://gavinb.net/2011/09/21/spservices-helper-function-resolve-the-guid-of-a-view/)